# PHP array_pop is not working

Tags: php

```
$fav = explode("|","0 | 1 | 2 | ");  
print_r($fav);  
$fav = array_pop($fav);  
echo "<br>after <br>";  
print_r($fav);
```

what's the problem in my code? i want to remove the last value in the array `$fav`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`array_pop` returns last value not remaining part.

so change this line `$fav = array_pop($fav);` to `array_pop($fav);`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the assigment, so it looks like this:

```
array_pop($fav);
```

[array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) returns the removed value and modifies the array in-place, so you must not assign the return value to the array variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php  
    $fav = explode("|","0 | 1 | 2 | ");  
    print_r($fav);  
    $remove_last= array_pop($fav);  
    echo "<br>after <br>";  
    print_r($fav);  
    ?>


    output

Array
    (
        [0] => 0 
        [1] =>  1 
        [2] =>  2 
        [3] =>  
    )
    after
Array
    (
        [0] => 0 
        [1] =>  1 
        [2] =>  2 
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the result of `array_pop` over the original array. Change that line to:

```
$removed = array_pop($fav);
```

Answer (score 1):

you've overwritten the variable `$fav`.
you also might want to remove the last `|` from your string that you explode.

```
<?php  
$fav = explode("|","0 | 1 | 2");  
print_r($fav);  // output should be: 0, 1, 2
$last_element = array_pop($fav);  
echo "<br>after <br>";  
print_r($fav);  // output should be: 0, 1
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

array_pop returns the remove element, not the array itself.

try this:

```
<pre>  
<?php  
$fav = explode("|","0 | 1 | 2 | ");  
print_r($fav);  
$last = array_pop($fav);  
echo "<br>after <br>";  
print_r($fav);  
?>  
</pre>
```